# How to insert content into an background image?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to adjust my h1 so that it will stay in the middle of the image but i can't figure the way to do it...can anyone help me? Thank you so much!

```css
.title {}

img {
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100vh;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <h1>DESIGN YOUR HOUSE</h1>
</div>

<img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/moose-at-maroon-lake-a-young-moose-with-only-one-antler-walking-and-picture-id1288537145?b=1&k=20&m=1288537145&s=170667a&w=0&h=DP5AU3_JBwGiCDJellQR6NMmrycDsrjd89yccPlVgJc=" />
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want the `H1` centred inside of the image?

Comment: yes, that's what i mean

Comment: You image is NOT a background.